# How Do I Make a Multi-filter Search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, search

I'm building an ecommerce site with Vanilla JS, Node and MongoDB. My search bar currently can only return searches based upon the name of the product as follows:

```
productRouter.get('/', expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const searchKeyword = req.query.searchKeyword
    ? {
        name: {
            $regex: req.query.searchKeyword,
            $options: 'i'
            }
        }
    : {};
    const products = await Product.find({...searchKeyword});
    res.send(products);
    })
);
```

I've tried adding category and brand inside of the ? {} like so to no avail:

```
? {
        name: {
            $regex: req.query.searchKeyword,
            $options: 'i'
            }, 
        category: {
            $regex: req.query.searchKeyword,
            $options: 'i'
            }, 
        brand: {
            $regex: req.query.searchKeyword,
            $options: 'i'
            }
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [search text](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/text/) feature.

It would be something like this:

```
// Creating compound index on db
db.product.createIndex({ name: 'text', category: 'text', brand: 'text' })

// Executing query
db.product.find({ $text: { $search: "something" } })
```

If you're using Mongoose, [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) is demonstrating how to create an index.